# Check: Find and plot all of the $6^{th}$ roots of unity and the $6^{th}$ roots of $7-3i$ .

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Find all of the $6^{th}$ roots of unity and the $6^{th}$ roots of $7-3i$ .

For each natural number $n$ there are exactly $n$ $n$-th roots of unity, which can be expressed as: $$z_k=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}k},k=0,1,\cdot, n-1$$ In our case $n=6$, hence, $$z_k=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{6}k}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}k},k=0,1,2,3,4,5$$

Thus, the $6$-th roots of $1$ are: $$z_0=e^{0i}=1, z_1=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}, z_2=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}, z_3=e^{i}=-1, z_4=e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}, z_5=e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}$$

So the $6^{th}$ roots of $7-3i$ are: $$
z_0=58^\frac{1}{12}e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}=1, 
z_1=58^\frac{1}{12}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}, 
z_2=58^\frac{1}{12}e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}, 
z_3=58^\frac{1}{12}e^{i\frac{7\pi}{6}}, 
z_4=58^\frac{1}{12}e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}},
z_5=58^\frac{1}{12}e^{i\frac{11\pi}{6}}$$

Comment: Typo : $e^i \neq -1$ ($e^{i\pi}$ does).

Comment: Thanks. But otherwise, is it correct?

Comment: No : for example, $z_1^6 = (58^{\frac{1}{12}}e^{\frac{5\pi}{6}})^6 = 58^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\pi} = -\sqrt{58} \neq 7 - 3i$

Comment: So how am I suppose to find the $6^{th}$ roots of $7-3i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start with finding the polar notation of $7 - 3i$ which is :
$$7-3i = \sqrt{58}e^{-i\tan^{-1}{(\frac{3}{7})}}$$

Then go even further to get only exponential :
$$7-3i = e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln{(58)}}e^{-i\tan^{-1}{(\frac{3}{7})}}$$

Now, it's pretty simple : the $n$th roots of $7-3i$ are :
$$e^{\frac{1}{2\cdot 6}\ln{(58)}}e^{-i\cdot \frac{1}{6}(\tan^{-1}{(\frac{3}{7})}+2k\pi)} \text{ for k in 0, ..., 6}$$
$$= \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}12]{58}e^{-i\cdot \frac{1}{6}(\tan^{-1}{(\frac{3}{7})}+2k\pi)} \text{ for k in 0, ..., 6}.$$

Generally speaking, for any complex $a$, the $n$th roots of unity are :
$$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{|a|}e^{i\frac{\arg(a)+2k\pi}{n}}\text{ for k in 0, ..., 6}.$$

Comment: Question: What if I had $12$ instead of $7-3i$? Would it be $tan^{-1}(0/12)$?

Comment: I edited. If you take $12$, $\arg(12) = 0$ and $|12| = 12$, hence it would be $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}6]{12}e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{6}}$

Comment: Actually, for any complex $c$ with a non-zero real part, $arg(c) = \tan^{-1}(\frac{\Im(c)}{\Re(c)})$, and yes, it will work with 12 (12 being also a complex number), as $\tan^{-1}(0) = 0$. For your complex number $7-3i$ it was simply $\tan^{-1}(\frac{-3}{7}) = -\tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{7})$ as $\tan^{-1}$ is odd.